# How to calculate the determinant of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I know determinant of Vandermonde matrix.

I have a matrix form from a Vandermonde matrix but by cutting its second column and its $k$-th row. Can anybody help me to calculate the determinant of the matrix?

From my observation to its pattern that the determinant of the matrix is \begin{eqnarray}\label{c4}
 &=& \dfrac{N!}{k(k-1)!(N-k)!}\prod\limits_{i=1}^N (N-i)!(\frac{1}{N}  + \cdots + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{1})
\end{eqnarray}

but I don't know how to prove this, please help me.

Comment: What actually is this Vandermonde matrix?

Comment: this is vandermonde matrix \begin{eqnarray}\label{a4}
|V_{N \times N}| =
\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
      {1} & {\lambda_1} & {\lambda_1^{2}} & \cdots & {\lambda_1^{N-1}} \\
      {1} & {\lambda_2} & {\lambda_2^{2}} & \cdots & {\lambda_2^{N-1}} \\
      {1} & {\lambda_3} & {\lambda_3^{2}} & \cdots & {\lambda_3^{N-1}} \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      {1} & {\lambda_n} & {\lambda_n^{2}}& \cdots & {\lambda_N^{N-1}}
      \end{array}\right| = \prod_{\substack{1 < i \leq N \\ 1 \leq j < N \\ j < i}} (\lambda_i-\lambda_j).
     \end{eqnarray}

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}\label{g2}
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
{1} & {1} & {1} & \cdots & {1} \\
{1} & {2} & {2^{2}} & \cdots & {2^{N-1}} \\
{1} & {3} & {3^{2}} & \cdots & {3^{N-1}} \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{1} & {N} & {N^{2}}& \cdots & {N^{N-1}}
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray}
diberikan oleh  
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha_N =\prod_{\substack{1 < i \leq N \\ 1 \leq j < N \\ j < i}}(i - j)= \prod\limits_{i=1}^N(N-i)!.\label{a6}
\end{eqnarray}